# LOCAL R Package not running because of missing doMC dependancy

Tags: r, dependencies, package

I am trying to get a local package to work but it depends on doMC which is only available for Mac and I don't have a Mac. Is there any way I can still make the package work? I use the following code:

```
install.packages("~/R/AMT/Code/CLVTools_1.0.5.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
```

After running the code I get the following error message:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/alexa_000/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)ERROR: dependency 'doMC' is not available for package 'CLVTools'
* removing 'C:/Users/alexa_000/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/CLVTools'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\alexa_000\Documents\R\win-library\3.0" "C:/Users/alexa_000/Documents/R/AMT/Code/CLVTools_1.0.5.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/alexa_000/Documents/R/AMT/Code/CLVTools_1.0.5.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to run the package anyways?

Any kind of help highly appreciated

Comment: If you know what functions in `CLVTools` you want to use, it might be worth checking to see if those specific functions require `doMC` . If they don't grab those functions' source and load them standalone.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/index.html), that package should run on any Unix system, not just `OS X`.

Your best bet is to install a virtual machine and put a Linux distro on it, or dual-boot your Windows PC with Linux.

More generally, if you are going to be doing a lot of data processing with open source tools like `R`, Linux is your friend.